# Megascans plugin error in Blender 2.9

Tags: python, import, error

Whenever I try to export a 3d asset from quixel bridge 2020.3.3 to blender 2.9 via megascans plugin, it shows exported successfully but there is no mesh that added to my scene, only the textures are exported but the not the mesh.

As soon as I open blender I make sure to click the megascans plugin, then I export 3d asset and then when I check the *Window > Toggle system console* it shows

```
Megascans Plugin Error while importing textures/geometry or setting up material. Error: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx" error, could not be found.
```

Comment: Same problem here, all other info I can find is from 3 years ago. Thought this would be solved by now.